# How to correctly make `WITH` SQL query with 2 other tables using the updated table?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I want to insert into 1 table and use the resulting id in 2 other tables.
For 1+1 table I would do:

```
WITH inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO whatever1 (
    whatever
  )
  VALUES('whatever')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO whatever2 (
  id
  whatever
)
SELECT
    inserted.id,
    'whatever'
FROM inserted
```

How to do the same for whatever3 as I did for whatever2 in a single query?
The documentation does not have useful examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

I came up with (but don't like it, because `whatever2` is never used):

```
WITH inserted1 AS (
  INSERT INTO whatever1 (
    whatever
  )
  VALUES('whatever')
  RETURNING id
),
inserted2 AS (
  INSERT INTO whatever2 (
    id
    whatever
  )
  SELECT
    inserted1.id,
    'whatever'
  FROM inserted1
)
INSERT INTO whatever3 (
  id
  whatever
)
SELECT
  inserted1.id,
  'whatever'
FROM inserted1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call all sections that you need. And in this case the id from section 2, is the same as section 1 and it's also the one you're using in your last INSERT statement. Something like this should work:

```
WITH    inserted1 AS (
    INSERT INTO whatever1 (whatever)
    VALUES('whatever')
    RETURNING 
        id
),  inserted2 AS (
    INSERT INTO whatever2 (id, whatever)
    SELECT
        inserted1.id,
        'whatever'
    FROM inserted1
    RETURNING
        id  -- actually inserted1.id
)
INSERT INTO whatever3 (id, whatever)
SELECT
    inserted1.id,
    'whatever'
FROM inserted2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to avoid storing the result of second insert with `inserted2 AS (..)`, because it won't be used, but if I can't avoid that, I use it like that :(